# What is the recommended way to handle (or suppress) exceptions thrown by an AutoCloseable?

Tags: java, try-with-resources

I am upgrading some existing APIs that take `Iterable`s to be `AutoCloseable`-sensitive. For example, given:

```
/**
 * @throws NoSuchElementException
 */
public static <T> T getOne(Iterable<T> iterable) {
  return iterable.iterator().next();
}
```

I would like the method to close the iterator if it is closable. Here's what I've got so far:

```
/**
 * @throws NoSuchElementException
 */
public static <T> T getOne(Iterable<T> iterable) {
  Iterator<T> iterator = iterable.iterator();
  try {
    return iterable.iterator().next();
  } finally {
    if (iterator instanceof AutoCloseable) {
      try {
        ((AutoCloseable) iterator).close();
      } catch (Exception ignored) {
        // intentionally suppressed
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Given how the JDK documentation refers to [`Throwable.getSuppressed()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getSuppressed%28%29), should this code be doing something akin to the following?

```
      } catch (Exception x) {
        RuntimeException rte = new RuntimeException("Could not close iterator");
        rte.addSuppressed(x);
        throw rte;
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best thing to do is simply piggy-back off the `try-with-resources` construct if you find that you have an `AutoCloseable`, something like this:

```
/**
 * @throws NoSuchElementException
 */
public static <T> T getOne(Iterable<T> iterable) {
  Iterator<T> iterator = iterable.iterator();
  if (iterator instanceof AutoCloseable) {
    try (AutoCloseable c = (AutoCloseable) iterator) {
      return iterator.next();
    }
  } else {
    return iterator.next();
  }
}
```

Then the language-level construct will take care of exceptions (including in the `close` method) in the correct way.